# How to count number and which annotations shown on MapView, when zooming?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I need to count number of annotations when i zooming mapView, and get array with which are shown on map, 
and then, i need to reload my Table and show list of only which shown on map.

How can i get number and array with annotation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about these two methods from MapKit class:

1) Get visible rectangle of map using:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CGRect annotationVisibleRect
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/annotationVisibleRect

2) Then get annotation NSSet from parameter map rectangle:

```
- (NSSet *)annotationsInMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/annotationsInMapRect:

So I would expect something like this:

```
-(void)getAnotationsInVisibleMapRectangle
{
    NSSet *annotationSet = [myMapView annotationsInMapRect:myMapView.annotationVisibleRect];

    // print number of annotations
    NSLog(@"Number of annotations in rect: %d", annotationSet.count);

    // this will return an array from the NSSet
    NSArray *annotationArray = [annotationSet allObjects]; 
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: It's nice, but need to convert CGRect (myMapView.annotationVisibleRect) to MKMapRect? "annotationInMapRect(MKMapRect)"...

Comment: Thanks! =) It help me) and i use "visibleMapRect" instead of "annotationVisibleRect"

Comment: 'annotationVisibleRect' does not compile so use 'visibleMapRect' as @Nubaslon noted.

Answer (score 12):

As for swift 2.0, I usually use this mapView extension to get all currently visible annotations as an array of MKAnnotations:

```
extension MKMapView {
    func visibleAnnotations() -> [MKAnnotation] {
        return self.annotationsInMapRect(self.visibleMapRect).map { obj -> MKAnnotation in return obj as! MKAnnotation }
    }
}
```

Comment: if some annotations are at the edge of the screen, it doesn't work

Comment: For that particular scenario, you could pass a bigger MapRect instead of the default visibleMapRect.

Answer (score 4):

David's great solution in Swift 4

```
extension MKMapView {
    func visibleAnnotations() -> [MKAnnotation] {
        return self.annotations(in: self.visibleMapRect).map { obj -> MKAnnotation in return obj as! MKAnnotation }
    }
}
```

Comment: All of the suggestions above don't work well if map is rotated.